# RabbitMQ-Overview dashboard no metrics data shown

Tags: grafana

I have a working bitnami/rabbitmq server helm chart working on my Kubernetes cluster but the graphs displayed on Grafana are not enough, I found this dashboard [RabbitMQ-Overview](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/10991) which has sufficient details that can be very useful for my bitnami/rabbitmq server but unfortunately there is no data showing on the dashboard. The issue here is I cannot see my metrics on this dashboard, can someone please suggest a work-around approach for my case. Please note I am using the kube-prometheus-stack helm chart for Prometheus+Grafana services.

Steps to solve this issue:

1. I enabled the rabbitmq_prometheus for all my Rabbitmq nodes by entering the Pods

   rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_prometheus

**Output:**

```
:/$ rabbitmq-plugins list
Listing plugins with pattern "." ...
Configured: E = explicitly enabled; e = implicitly enabled
| Status: * = running on rabbit@rabbitmq-0.broker-server
|/
[E] rabbitmq_management 3.8.9
[e*] rabbitmq_management_agent 3.8.9
[ ] rabbitmq_mqtt 3.8.9
[e*] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_common 3.8.9
[E*] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_k8s 3.8.9
[E*] rabbitmq_prometheus 3.8.9
```

2. Made sure I was using the same data source for Prometheus used in my Grafana
3. I tried creating a prometheus-rabbitmq-exporter to get the metrics from Rabbitmq and send them to RabbitMQ-Overview dashboard but no data was displayed.

[my dashboard no data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1FAp.png)

4. Please note while reading this [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/prometheus.html#rabbitmq-configuration) to solve my issue I already have metrics from Rabbitmq displayed on Grafana but I need the RabbitMQ-Overview that contains more details about my server.

Answer (score 2):

To build on @amin 's answer, the label can be added to the helm like so:

Before helm chart version 9.0.0

```
metrics:
  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: true
    additionalLabels:
      release: prometheus
```

After helm chart version 9.0.0

```
metrics:
  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: true
    labels:
      release: prometheus
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue after including 2 commands from this table [table](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/rabbitmq#metrics-parameters) and need to edit the ServiceMonitor to include the label `release: prometheus` as it is needed to be visible in the prometheus targets as I am using kube-prometheus-stack helm chart.

```
helm install -f values.yml broker bitnami/rabbitmq --namespace default --set nodeSelector.test=rabbit --set volumePermissions.enabled=true --set replicaCount=1 --set metrics.enabled=true --set metrics.serviceMonitor.enabled=true
```

I hope it helps someone in the future!